# Как поменять уровень защиты в Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, ассемблер, прерывания

Есть такой кусок кода на **ассемблере**, написанный в *Visual Studio 2008*:

```
int main()
{
  short a;
  __asm
  {
    int 11h
    mov a,ax
  }
  printf("%d",a);
  return 0;
}
```

Короче ничего интересного, но проблема в том, что при запуске, на строке прерывания `int 11h`, происходит ошибка, я покапался по интернету и нашел, что есть в *Visual Studio* какая-то защита от прерываний, подскажите пожайлуста, где её найти и как её отключить.

Comment: У вас смесь кода дос (прерывания int), и виндовс (printf). Это не будет работать в защищённом режиме под Windows.

Comment: А как его отключить?

Comment: Раздобудьте себе 486 пентиум поставьте дос и наслаждайтесь древностью

Comment: Это конечно смешно, но почему тогда есть вставка __asm? Все собирается, только во время работы на прерывании вылетает ошибка.

Comment: @Fedor - потому что на ассемблере можно (но в современной практике, скорее всего, не нужно) много чего делать, например, вызывать инструкции AVX и делать оптимизации вручную. Ломается только из-за того, что вы полезли к привелигерованным инструкциям.

Comment: Я это знаю, но мне нужна обработка прерываний. На форуме, где я это прочитал говорилось о том, что надо поменять уровень защиты, но как не говорилось, а человек, который нашел решение, по классике не стал рассказывать как, вот я и спрашиваю тут как.

Comment: @Fedor для этого ваша программа должна быть написана как драйвер и запущена соответсвующим образом. Только учтите, что знания прерываний от DOS вам не помогут.

Comment: Есть такое понятие как "вектор (адрес) обработчика прерываний". Когда вы в реальном режиме под MS-DOS, то биос выстаивает таблицу векторов всех прерываний в IVT по физическому адресу нуль. Но когда Windows переходит в свой защищённый режим, то IVT уже не используется, а на её место Win выстраивает свою таблицу IDT (int descriptor table), куда для некоторых прерываний (типа int-3) прописываются новые вектора, которые указывают уже на вирт.память. Таким образом прежнего int-11h может уже вообще не быть, а если и есть, то выполняет совсем иную задачу.

Comment: Вставка __asm сохранена с частичной работоспособностью в компиляторе для 32-битных приложений для обеспечения частичной обратной совместимости. В компиляторе для 64-битных приложений ее уже нет.

Answer (score 1):

прерывание INT 11h возвращает состав оборудования, тебе нужно разобраться какое оборудование нужно для выполнения твой программы и узнать об его наличии посредством Win32.

никаких других законных способов заставить этот код работать нет.